# I can not test my App on my device anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I updated my Xcode 8  to Xcode 8.2 to make it work with iOS 10.2, but now when I try to run my app on my device, I get the following error:

`**The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.**

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).`

I have spent hours on this, but haven't really found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Has your Apple Developer Program membership expired? If so, that would disable some entitlements. For example, you cannot send push notifications without a valid Developer Program membership, among other capabilities like CloudKit and Apple Pay.

I used to know of a table on the Apple Developer site which listed the differences, but I can't find it now. If I track it down, I'll edit with a link.

Other than that, you'd probably also want to try signing out and signing back in under Preferences > Accounts. Perhaps something odd just randomly happened with the provisioning profile.